# checking file size before uploading image using multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, multer

how can I use the submiting data related to image pass to server using multer before uploading it to disk .Is it possible ? if not then please give me another solution.
I want to check the size of file its should be at least 4mp resolution ,if its has lesser then that the images should not be uploaded and send the error msg

```
exports.uploadimg=(req,res,next)=>{
  
    uploadphoto(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.render("upload")
        }
        else {


    
            

          


           
            res.send("photo uloaded")
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it you have some multipart middleware (say [connect-multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-multiparty)) reading request payload for `multipart/form-data` requests.

This middleware would have provided you with a `files` object on the `request` object (`request.files`). The properties of the `files` object are keys for each file upload field. The value for each of such property can be an object (a single file upload) or an array (multiple files upload). Each of these objects nested within the `files` object have properties describing the actual file uploaded and allows you to run checks as you see fit in a following middleware.

```js
// router declarations
const {Router} = require('express');
const multipart = require('connect-multipart');

const multipartMiddleware = multipart();

const validateFileSize = (file) => {
  /*
      Each file has the following property:

        fieldName - same as name - the field name for this file
        originalFilename - the filename that the user reports for the file
        path - the absolute path of the uploaded file on disk
        headers - the HTTP headers that were sent along with this file
        size - size of the file in bytes
    */
    // check against file size
    if (file.size < 4 * 1024 * 1024) throw new Error('File is too small');
}

const validateImageMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  // say we expected an upload field with key "productImage"
  const { files: { productImage } } = req;
  const isMultiple = Array.isArray(productImage);
  if (isMultiple) {
    productImage.forEach(validateFileSize);
  } else {
    validateFileSize(productImage);
  }
  // if we got here, the files were valid so we go to next handler
  next();
};

const myRouter = Router();
myRouter.post('/expect-file', multipartMiddleware, validateImageMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  // do whatever you want to do
  res.send('Success');
});
```

Comment: i am using multer for uploading images. but its does not provide any size of image before its gettingbuplkkoad .however if we use the req object  outside the multer call i.e beforew uplaoding file its show req.body empty and if we use inside multer call i.e after images has saved or upload req.body has the required data.

Comment: since i am using multipart/form-data may its happing because of it.do u know some other way soo that i can do above problem also i had pass categories and before uploading it i have to check the image for which categories its belonging and accordingly i have to save it into respective image folder iam stuck here help me for this.

Comment: Have you tried passing the `validateFileSize` function (as above or implemented however you want) as next middleware after your multer middleware placement in the router specification?

Comment: Check `req.file` (if single image) or `req.files` (for multiple)